# routing 2 urls to 1 handler

Tags: python, url-routing, tornado

I'm trying to implement some sort of API on tornado and I have such question:
is it possible to route two urls to one handler separating by method.

```
class Handler():
   def get(self):
       #only for the first url
   def post(self):
       #only for the secornd url
handlers = [
   (r"/url1",Handler), #only GET are allowed
   (r"/url2",Handler), #only POST are allowed
]
```

So if someone trying to send POST to the first url he should see error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want to do is to use regex in your url and check for the attribute in your methods handler.

Example of urls to map

```
url_patterns = [
    # here we want to map url1 url2 and url
    (r"/url([1|2])/", OneAndTwoHandler),
]
```

And an example of the corresponding handler

```
class OneAndTwoHandler(CustomRequestHandler):
    def get(self, my_param, *args, **kwargs):
        if my_param == '2':
            raise HTTPError(405)
        # code for only the first url here...

    def post(self, entry, *args, **kwargs):
        if my_param == '1':
            raise HTTPError(405)
        # code for only the first url here...
```

I would map 'my_param' options to a dictionary to keep things clear and to avoid me to dive into the handler if I need to change these values or if I want to add new urls.

```
my_dict_urls = {
    'get': (1,2,3,4),
    'post': (3,5)
}

if int(my_param) not in my_dict_urls.get('get'):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use @ee_vin's answer to do this. However, in this situation, why not create two handlers? It's much simpler:

```
class OneHandler():
   def get(self):
       #only for the first url

class TwoHandler():
   def post(self):
       #only for the second url

handlers = [
   (r"/url1",OneHandler), #only GET are allowed
   (r"/url2",TwoHandler), #only POST are allowed
]
```

Anyone posting to the first URL or GETting the second would get a method not supported error.